# z-index not working with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress site. I am currently using BeTheme on my site. There is an issue in responsive header menu. 
Site Link: http://swedesuccess.com.au/newsite/

For small screens/devices with resolution 980, 800, 786 (in width), menu is not displaying. When "menu-header-menu-container" position set as "unset", menu will display. Also when I apply z-index to "menu-header-menu-container", it's not working. Menu layer is still hiding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: May be you got solution from this demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/P7c9q/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wrapper`has `overflow_hidden` remove it and you should see your menu. it's not a `z-index` problem. add:

```
#Wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

to your css